# Apache Airflow GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator - time_partitioning operator

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow

I’m using GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator. I want to load the data in a CSV file from GCS to BQ with time partition set to ‘hour’. I have used the parameter:

```
 time_partitioning = [‘hr’]
```

However, the data got loaded at Day level partition. Could someone point to the parameters that ‘time_partitioning’ takes? I want the ingested partition at the hour level.

Answer (score 2):

timePartitioning is actually dict object, not a list.

```
:param time_partitioning: configure optional time partitioning fields i.e.
    partition by field, type and  expiration as per API specifications.
    .. seealso::
        https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timePartitioning
:type time_partitioning: dict
```

You can refer above cloud link to setup time_partitioning field and type(HOUR/DAY).

***GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator*** class is deprecated so you could start use  ***GCSToBigQueryOperator*** operator.

Answer (score 0):

Using GCSToBigQueryOperator and passing the parameter as below as resolved the issue:

time_partitioning = {'type':'HOUR'}

The details of GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator being deprecated and replaced by GCSToBigQueryOperator can be found [here](http://%20https://github.com/apache/airflow/tree/master/airflow/providers/google#moved-transfer-operators)